# pandas: apply random.shuffle() to list column

Tags: python, pandas, random, lambda, shuffle

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'text':['The weather is nice','the house is amazing','the flowers are blooming']})
```

I would like to shuffle the words in each row using random.shuffle(),(e.g the new first row will be 'nice is weather the' ),so I have done the following,

```
df.new_text = df.text.str.split()
```

and tried to map or apply shuffle() function but it returns None.

```
print(df.new_text.map(lambda x: random.shuffle(x)))
```

or

```
print(df.new_text.apply(lambda x: random.shuffle(x)))
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. and then finally I would like to join the shuffled words in the list to get a string per row,

```
df.new_text = df.new_text.apply( lambda x:' '.join(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job.

```
shuffled_sentences = {"text":[]}

for sentence in df.values.ravel():
  np.random.shuffle(sentence)
  shuffled_sentences["text"].append(sentence)

shuffled_df = pd.DataFrame(shuffled_sentences)
```

The thing with `np.random.shuffle` is that it doesn't return any output. So you need to store the list you want to shuffle in a vraible first. Then if you apply `np.random.shuffle` on it, the original variable itself would be shuffled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.random.permutation` from numpy library

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'text':['The weather is nice','the house is amazing','the 
flowers are blooming']})

df['new_text']= df['text'].apply(lambda x:x.split())
df['new_text']= df['new_text'].map(lambda x:  np.random.permutation(x))
df['new_text']= df['new_text'].apply( lambda x:' '.join(x))


display(df.new_text)
0         nice weather is The
1        the is house amazing
2    flowers are the blooming
```

Comment: This is one cool solution to `random.shuffle` not returning any output!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) does the shuffle in place and does not return any output. You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) instead:

```
df['new_text'] = df['text'].str.lower().str.split()
df['new_text'] = df['new_text'].apply(lambda x: random.sample(x, k=len(x)))
```

Resulting values:

```
0         [is, weather, the, nice]
1        [amazing, house, is, the]
2    [are, blooming, flowers, the]
Name: new_text, dtype: object
```